# Similar lists are different when using SequenceEquals

Tags: c#

I have the following lists:

```
List<Person> a = new List<Person> {
  new Person {
    Id = 1,
    Address = new Address { PersonId = 1 }
  }
};

List<Person> b = new List<Person> {
  new Person {
    Id = 1,
    Address = new Address { PersonId = 1 }
  }
};

var r = a.SequenceEqual(b);
```

Even if the lists are identical "r" is false ... What am I missing?

Is there a way to compare these two lists and have true as a result?

Comment: You need to implement IEqualityComparer on your Person class, and return True if the Id and Address are the same. See this article, it should point you in the right direction https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, those 2 lists are different since there the proson object that you are using is different. You newed person twice which means the memory allocated for the first one is not the same as the second one. But since your problem is to compare lists with the same items, you just need to implement IEquatable as described in here
[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx)

So your code will be like this:

```
class Person:IEquatable<Person>
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public bool Equals(Person other)
 {

return Id== other.Id;
}
}
```

.
.

```
List<Person> a = new List<Person> {
  new Person {
    Id = 1    
  }
};

List<Person> b = new List<Person> {
  new Person {
    Id = 1    
  }
};

var r = a.SequenceEqual(b);
```

Comment: You should always also override `object.Equals` when you implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: Essentially because `IEquatable` isn’t used everywhere and other code can and will still use `object.Equals`, which will introduce inconsistent behavior. See also [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatablet-you-still-must-override-objects-equals-and-gethashcode/) on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

The `a` and `b` contains two completely different objects. The SequenceEquals checks for the references of the objects contained in the sequences. Since those are different, `a.SequenceEquals(b)` returns false.

Specifically, the following:

```
var person = new Person { Id = 1, Address = new Address { PersonId = 1 } };
```

creates a `Person` object and returns a reference to this object in the variable `person`. Each time you call `new Person { ... }` a new object is created an a new reference is returned pointing to this object, despite the fact that `Id` is the same in both cases. In For the same reason, `Address` in `a` and `b` are two completely different references, despite the fact the `PersonId` is 1.

On the other hand, if we had the following statements:

```
var person = new Person { Id = 1, Address = new Address { PersonId = 1 } };
var a = new List<Person> { person };
var b = new List<Person> { person };
```

`a.SequenceEquals(b)` would have returned true.

Answer (score 1):

Both lists contain two *different* person instances. Those person object appear to have the same values, but they are not equal.

`a.SequenceEqual(b)` is only true, if `a[i] == b[i]` for all indexes `i`. So it’s still doing a comparison of persons here.

You need to override the `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) method for your `Person` type (and possibly `Address` too) in order for this to work.